# Botao FAB não fica no lugar

Tags: android, android-layout

Não sei o que está acontecendo o botão FAB sobe em cima de outro componente na hora de compilar, mas no preview ele fica certo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.rbxsoft.rbxsalesforce.CaixaDeEntradaActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/caixaDeEntrada"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabNovoPedido"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="292dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="439dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Aqui mostra como fica depois que compila]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele não fica no lugar porque tu não aplicou nenhuma `constraint` para ele. E o editor deve te avisar isto com um sinal de `warning`. Os atributos `editor_absoluteY/X` só servem pra dar um efeito visual no editor, eles não vão posicionar tua `view` como você quer que ela fique.

Leia um pouco sobre [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), porque para posicionar as suas `views`, você vai precisar conectar elas uma às outras, criando `nodes`. No próprio editor você consegue fazer isso.

Outra coisa, nenhuma das suas `views` estão conectadas corretamente, porque você apenas jogou elas no seu **Layout**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.rbxsoft.rbxsalesforce.CaixaDeEntradaActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/caixaDeEntrada" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabNovoPedido"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

O código acima deve funcionar como desejado. Abaixo explicarei algumas coisas importantes que eu adicionei no seu layout.

Observação: o valor **0dp** é como **mach_parent**.

---

**layout_constraintStart**

Esse atributo vai alinhar o **começo** da sua **view** com outra parte de outra **view** ou do **parent** (que no caso é o próprio *Constraint Layout*).

Pode usar ela com os seguintes **atributos**: `_toStartOf` e `_toEndOf`.

---

**layout_constraintEnd**

É a mesma coisa do atributo anterior, mas ele alinha a parte direita da sua **view** com outra **view**/**parent**.

Pode ser usada com: `_toStartOf` e `_toEndOf`

---

**layout_constraintTop**

Também é a mesma coisa da anterior, mas alinha a parte superior e lembra muito o atributo `layout_below` do `RelativeLayout` se combinada com `_toBottomOf`.

Pode ser usada com: `_toTopOf` e `_toBottomOf`.

---

**layout_constraintBottom**

Alinha a parte inferior e lembra o atributo `layout_above` do `RelativeLayout` se combinada com `_toTopOf`.

Pode ser usada com: `_toTopOf` e `_toBottomOf`.